# Parent class toggle

Tags: jquery

Trying to toggle parent class, but it is affecting every time for every child element, I need when I click on ANCHCHOR tag it's parent LI only get class.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/yoxw8uvd/7/)**

```
$(".nav-link.dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.nav-item.dropdown').removeClass('dropdown-toggle-arrow');  
    $(this).closest('.nav-item.dropdown').toggleClass('dropdown-toggle-arrow');     
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best option is to use the events of the [bootstrap dropdown component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/dropdowns/#events).

Here is a solution how to do it, based on the example from your question:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.navbar .nav-item').on('show.bs.dropdown', dropDownToggle);
  $('.navbar .nav-item').on('hide.bs.dropdown', dropDownToggle);

  function dropDownToggle(event) {
    var currentTarget = $(event.currentTarget);

    currentTarget.siblings('.nav-item.dropdown').removeClass('dropdown-toggle-arrow');
    currentTarget.toggleClass('dropdown-toggle-arrow');
  }

});
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle-arrow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">N</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav-link.dropdown-toggle").click(function() { 
  // Check if clicked parent already have class, then remove
  if($(this).closest('.nav-item.dropdown').hasClass('dropdown-toggle-arrow')) {
    $(this).closest('.nav-item.dropdown').removeClass('dropdown-toggle-arrow'); 
  } else {
    // First remove class from all element parents
    $(this).closest('.navbar-nav').find('.nav-item.dropdown').removeClass('dropdown-toggle-arrow');
    // Then add class to clicked element's parent
    $(this).closest('.nav-item.dropdown').addClass('dropdown-toggle-arrow');   
  }         
});
```

Comment: Your code can be minimized and should really use a variable for `$(this)`. Also, if the user clicks outside the menu and the dropdown closes, your function will not work properly.